# The program behavoir is different on different systems. why ?

Tags: c#

This is the code of my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace YourGold
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to YourGold App! \n------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Inesrt your gold: ");
            int gold;
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out gold))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number for gold.");
                Console.WriteLine("Inesrt your gold: ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Inesrt your time(In Hours) played: ");
            float hours;
            while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out hours))                
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number for hours.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Inesrt your hours played: ");
                    }
                    float time = ((int)hours) * 60 + (hours % 1) * 100; ; // Here the calculation are wrong...
                    Console.WriteLine("Your total time playd is : " + time + " minutes");
                    float goldMin = gold / time;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your gold per minute is : " + goldMin);
                    Console.WriteLine("The application has ended, press any key to end this app. \nThank you for using it.\n but no thanks");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    //Console.WriteLine(" \nApp self destruct!");
                    //Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it using my local Visual Studio environment, I see in my console that the output of `minutes` is equals to `900` when passing `1.5` hours into my program.

If I run this on `www.ideone.com`, I see that the output is `90 minutes` for the same value `1.5`.

Where could I make a mistake in my code ? 
Why the behaviour of my program is different when running in different places ?

Comment: You should consider giving good title for your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly suspect that when you run it locally, you're in a culture where `,` is the decimal separator rather than `.` - and perhaps `.` is the thousands separator, which is basically ignored. So `1.5` ends up being parsed as 15 hours, which is 900 minutes.

To validate this, try entering `1,5` instead - I suspect you'll then get a result of 90.

If you want to enforce settings where `.` is the decimal separator, simply pass a culture into `float.TryParse`:

```
while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Float,
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out hours))
```

Note that you don't need to do all the arithmetic yourself - use `TimeSpan` to do it for you.

```
int minutes = (int) TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).TotalMinutes;
```